# Extract only the data for the numeric features in mydata, along with Class, and store them as a separate data frame/tibble

Tags: r

My data frame contains both continuous and categorical features. I need to extract only the continuous/numeric data as well as the Class feature and store it in a separate data frame or tibble. New to R and could really use some help.

Unsure of how to extract the data. As I said earlier I am really new to R and am struggling. Thanks